# What is the complete list of configurable properties supported by javax.xml and Xerces?

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I am working on tuning a Java application that uses Xerces. I solved some deadlocking by following advice from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344031/high-lock-contention-in-sun-misc-urlclasspath-getloader-under-jaxb-unmarshaller) and [blogs](https://www.databasesandlife.com/java-always-explicitly-specify-which-xml-parser-to-use/) to explicitly set a system property to make `DocumentBuilder` instantiation faster:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory",
    "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

I would like to know what other configurable options are supported by `javax.xml` generally and by Xerces specifically. I cannot locate this in a manual, user guide, nor JavaDoc. Does a comprehensive list of these options exist?

Comment: Why are you tuning it? Is it running slow? Perhaps you could provide the reason for tuning, some benchmarks, for example.

Comment: The specific tuning I've done thus far has been based on a thread dump showing blocking operations in the `org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory.findJarServiceProvider` method. These are outlined in the links I provided. What I hope to learn by seeing a complete listing of options for `javax.xml` or Xerces is what other options exist so I can then infer what hotspots to look for or just outright disable unused features.

Comment: The source should be kind of comprehensive: https://github.com/apache/xerces2-j/blob/trunk/src/org/apache/xerces/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling for "Xerces configuration properties" takes you straight to

https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/

which has links for "properties" and "features" at the bottom of the page.

Not sure why you found this difficult.

Comment: "Not sure why you found this difficult." - That link was in my history. I think I was looking for the "org.foo.bar" property name style as opposed to the URL style xerces uses. Commenting in case someone else falls into the same mistake. Thank you for answering.